# Coveo search with sitecore

Tags: sitecore, coveo

I am making a test page in sitecore after integrating coveo search, when I make a simple coveo search page and do just the minor changing like including a facet etc it work fine and give desired results but the problem is page don't save upon pressing save button. It gives following error

[image]

I am beginner in sitecore and just can't figure out why it don't save.

I am using sitecore 8.1

Comment: What does your sitecore logs say?

Comment: Where can I see the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: https://developers.coveo.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=33587260

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the link given below and it worked in my case.

[Save Return Error in Sitecore Page Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029713/save-return-error-in-sitecore-page-editor/35443212#35443212).